# Rails routing error: No route matches [POST] "/students/1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a routing error: No route matches [POST] "/students/1" that I can't figure out.  Here are the details.

view code:

```
<% @students.each do |student| %>
.
.
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', student %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(student) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Select Subjects', select_path(student) %></td>  # error occurs here
```

In my students controller:

```
def select
  .
  .
end
```

routes.rb:
    HomeSchool::Application.routes.draw do

```
  resources :notes

  resources :assignments

  resources :subjects do
    resources :assignments, :only => [:create, :index, :new]
  end

  resources :students

  resources :resources

  match "students/:id/select" => "students#select", :as => :select

  root :to => 'students#index'

end
```

The output from rake routes is:

```
                       GET    /students/:id/select(.:format)                  students/:id#select
                 notes GET    /notes(.:format)                                notes#index
                       POST   /notes(.:format)                                notes#create
              new_note GET    /notes/new(.:format)                            notes#new
             edit_note GET    /notes/:id/edit(.:format)                       notes#edit
                  note GET    /notes/:id(.:format)                            notes#show
                       PUT    /notes/:id(.:format)                            notes#update
                       DELETE /notes/:id(.:format)                            notes#destroy
           assignments GET    /assignments(.:format)                          assignments#index
                       POST   /assignments(.:format)                          assignments#create
        new_assignment GET    /assignments/new(.:format)                      assignments#new
       edit_assignment GET    /assignments/:id/edit(.:format)                 assignments#edit
            assignment GET    /assignments/:id(.:format)                      assignments#show
                       PUT    /assignments/:id(.:format)                      assignments#update
                       DELETE /assignments/:id(.:format)                      assignments#destroy
   subject_assignments GET    /subjects/:subject_id/assignments(.:format)     assignments#index
                       POST   /subjects/:subject_id/assignments(.:format)     assignments#create
new_subject_assignment GET    /subjects/:subject_id/assignments/new(.:format) assignments#new
              subjects GET    /subjects(.:format)                             subjects#index
                       POST   /subjects(.:format)                             subjects#create
           new_subject GET    /subjects/new(.:format)                         subjects#new
          edit_subject GET    /subjects/:id/edit(.:format)                    subjects#edit
               subject GET    /subjects/:id(.:format)                         subjects#show
                       PUT    /subjects/:id(.:format)                         subjects#update
                       DELETE /subjects/:id(.:format)                         subjects#destroy
              students GET    /students(.:format)                             students#index
                       POST   /students(.:format)                             students#create
           new_student GET    /students/new(.:format)                         students#new
          edit_student GET    /students/:id/edit(.:format)                    students#edit
               student GET    /students/:id(.:format)                         students#show
                       PUT    /students/:id(.:format)                         students#update
                       DELETE /students/:id(.:format)                         students#destroy
             resources GET    /resources(.:format)                            resources#index
                       POST   /resources(.:format)                            resources#create
          new_resource GET    /resources/new(.:format)                        resources#new
         edit_resource GET    /resources/:id/edit(.:format)                   resources#edit
              resource GET    /resources/:id(.:format)                        resources#show
                       PUT    /resources/:id(.:format)                        resources#update
                       DELETE /resources/:id(.:format)                        resources#destroy
                select        /students/:id/select(.:format)                  students#select
                  root        /                                               students#index
```

Any suggestions?  I'm having a really hard time grasping exactly how routing in rails is supposed to work and I have yet to find any kind of treatise on it but I'm pretty sure that having no method listed for my select route is at least part of my problem.

Thanks,

Lon

Comment: Are you sure the error happens in the line you are saying?

Comment: There is something somewhere that is not in your question. Notice the line at the top of your rake:routes -- `GET /students/:id/select(.:format) students/:id#select`.  First of all there is only a GET method defined for this.  Second, there is no controller for `students/:id` to have a select action on.  Nothing in the routes.rb file would cause this.  I'm actually interested in how you got it to think that your controller name was `students/:id.`  If you get rid of whatever is causing that it should work fine, however, shioyama's solution is more elegant.

Comment: Ok, fixed now, but I have no idea how I got it to think I had a students/:id controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `match` in your `routes.rb` file and change your `students` resource to this:

```
resources :students do
  member do
    get 'select'
  end
end
```

Also update your view to call `select_student_path(student)`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of your routes.rb file. It doesn't have a callback for post method in "/students/new"

To correct this.
Go to routes.rb and add `post 'students/new' to: 'students#new'` before end.

and check `rails routes`. you will find a routing path there for the post.